# How to change the listbox's content by the selection of the combobox C#

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

Hey I am working on a project where, based on what the user has selected in the combobox, code that is related to what the user has selected appears in the listbox. Here is what I have so far

```
public Form2()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        majorComboBox.Items.Add("Computer Science");
        majorComboBox.Items.Add("Business");
    }

private void majorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (majorComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0) ;
            {
                 courseListBox.Items.Add("Computer Science");
            }
        if (majorComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1) ;
        {
            courseListBox.Items.Add("Business");
        }
```

When I run this code and select Computer Science or Business from the combobox both Computer Science and Business show up in the list box. I am lost and would appreciate any guidance on the subject. This is my first question I have posted so if you need more information please ask and I will try to explain more.

Comment: Remove the semicolons from the end of your if statements    if (majorComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` sentence must not end with a semicolon.

```
private void majorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (majorComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
         courseListBox.Items.Add("Computer Science");
    }

    if (majorComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        courseListBox.Items.Add("Business");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Still getting the hang of these freaking semi colons haha